# Where to submit pull requests for keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pull-request

### Question:

I'm wondering; where should pull requests for keras be pushed?
- On github.com/keras-team/keras ?
- On github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras ?
 - Or for tf.v2: github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/keras?

I'm asking because I met a bug which was somehow simple but hard for me to figure out; I mixed my python imports between `tf.keras` and `keras` itself and some functions don't behave exactly the same.

I originally thought that "all that was in keras standalone was also in tf". Which appeared to be false.

In addition, how are updates from `keras` standalone pushed to `tf.keras`?

Is there any selection, refinement from the tensorflow team to integrate or are they automatically pushed?

*(If I'm not asking at the right place, let me know...)*

Answer (score 1):

You can find the keras contributing guidelines [here](https://keras.io/contributing/) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md), it tells you how/where to report your bug. Either you submit your pull request to the [master](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master) or [to the issue reporting](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues). When filing the bug you are asked what backend you use, I assume that you can get help on the integration with tensorflow there as well, as keras is supposed to handle the backend.

I couldn't find (yet) when tensorflow takes updates from keras, so I cannot answer that part of the question.

Comment: So the best way would be; PR -> keras-team then its integration to tensorflow is done "somewhere in the cloud by really nice devs" if I understand correctly?

Comment: How do they handle PR to tf.keras in the tf team? They don't care about that? Or do they ask for changes from keras itself and systematically reject direct PR? Or do they inform keras-team about PR so that they are merged there instead of directly to tf.keras?

Comment: @s.k I could find the `comp:keras` tag on the [tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues?q=keras+label%3Acomp%3Akeras). I guess that comp is for compatibility. If you follow the community guidelines when doing a PR they would redirect you (if they thought you were addressing the wrong community).